# Fusioncharts server side export is not working in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, export, fusioncharts

I have problem trying to setup Fusioncharts server side export. I have simple chart and then I select to export data, FCExporter.php requires resources **Resources/FCExporter_IMAGE-DATA2XLSX.php**. This file don't exist in their given developer bundle. How can I fix it?

Comment: In DATA2XLSX, xlsx can be svg, pdf depending on what type I choose to export

Comment: Please go to FusionCharts download folder, inside that there would integrations folder, inside which there would be PHP folder inside that chart-export-handler folder there FCExporter.php file is located.

Comment: Yup I have that, but FCExporter requires Resources folder and files with Images-data in the name

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure, you have set proper path for the following elements in the FCExporter.php file.

define ( "SAVE_PATH", "../resources/chartexporter/charts/" ) Can you set it to this and try? : define ( "SAVE_PATH", "./" )

And also, you would need to specify the path for this element ( "HTTP_URI", "path of the folder in which FCExporter file exists" );

How does it work-

Step 1: A chart is rendered in the browser.

Step 2: When an export option is selected, the chart generates the SVG string that represents the current state and sends it to the export server.

Step 3: The export server captures the SVG string.

Step 4: The export server invokes a system call triggering Inkscape to convert the FusionCharts generated SVG string (which is passed to the server-side script over AJAX) to PDF, PNG, and SVG. However, Inkscape still has a limitation of generating a JPG file. Hence, ImageMagick is used to create the JPG files. To export chart data as XLSX, the CSV data generated from the charts is converted to the XLSX format.

To know more about this feature please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/exporting-charts/using-fc-export-server/server-side-export/setup-private-export-server/php